# magento 1.9 duplicate orders

Tags: magento-1.9

Duplicate order on Magento v 1.9.2.0., triggered by

When we click checkout button than order repeated 3 times.

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using any custom extension for the checkout?

Since when your problem exists ?

```sql
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(o.quote_id) 
FROM sales_flat_order as o
WHERE o.quote_id = q AND o.grand_total = grandtotal
group by o.quote_id) as count 
FROM sales_flat_order having count > 1 
order by quote_id desc, created_at desc;
```

Comment: Yes I used Lotus Breath - One Step Checkout extensions version 4.1.2. Same extension works great on other store.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to prevent multiple checkout button clicks is to disable it using javascript, after first click, like this :

```
getElementById('checkoutButton').disabled = true;
```

and don't forget to re-enable it, in case an error occured (i.e : after an ajax call)

```
getElementById('checkoutButton').disabled = false;
```